# Semantic UI Grid disable equal height columns to get smaller columns to stack

Tags: css, grid

I have two different widget-categories with different width and heights. 
The big widget has 2x the width and height of the small widget.

Now I specify the column width depending on the screen size  with the semantic ui classes like "six wide widescreen" and so on.
So the order is first all big widgets and then the small widgets get displayed.
On Computer and tablet size first two big widgets get the class eight wide each so they take the first row on their own.
On wide screen I give the big widgets only six wide so both just take 12 of the 16 columns per row so 2 columns of the small widgets can get up to the first row.

The Html

```
<div  class="ui internally celled stackable grid" >
  <div class="row">
    <div style="background-color: blue; height: 600px;" class="column six wide widescreen eight wide computer eight wide tablet sixteen wide mobile">
      Big Widget 1
    </div>
    <div style="background-color: green; height: 600px;" class="column six wide widescreen eight wide computer eight wide tablet sixteen wide mobile">
      Big Widget 2
    </div>
    <div style="background-color: red; height: 300px;" class="column two wide widescreen two wide large-screen four wide computer eight wide mobile four wide tablet">
      Small Widget 1
    </div>
    <div style="background-color: orange; height: 300px;" class="column two wide widescreen two wide large-screen four wide computer eight wide mobile four wide tablet">
      Small Widget 2
    </div>
    <div style="background-color: purple; height: 300px;" class="column two wide widescreen two wide large-screen four wide computer eight wide mobile four wide tablet">
      Small Widget 3
    </div>
    <div style="background-color: gray; height: 300px;" class="column two wide widescreen two wide large-screen four wide computer eight wide mobile four wide tablet">
      Small Widget 4
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Codepen Demo](https://codepen.io/Nisatru/pen/vWqVvL)

Now my question: The Small widgets have exactly the half height of the big widgets so the white space underneath the 2 small widgets in widescreen mode could be filled with the third and fourth small widget.

Is there a way to break the first two small widgets columns by half to fit the third and fourth widget in the first row?

[How it looks right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ga3Tv.png)

[How I want it to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4zMP.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got it done based on the built-in CSS Grid instead of the external library you used. Please see the [Codepen Demo](https://codepen.io/goodman2017/pen/MONWGM).

I have not touched the <body> part of your HTML, but I've removed the two files you referred to in your <head>.  And then added the following CSS:

```
.row{
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 300px 300px 300px;
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
}
.six{
  grid-column: span 2;
  grid-row: span 2;
}
```

Now CSS Grid is supported by mainstream browsers with built-in CSS. No need to depend on any other libraries. If you search for "CSS Grid", there are quite some tutorials available.

Hope this helps.